# GSON how to exclude a property at second level of serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, circular-reference

I building a web api with Jersey and JaxRs and I am searching a way to prevent GSON from serializing à circular reference. I have found a lot of answers saying that in the case of a "parent > child" relation, we could add the `transient` keyword to the parent property so it won't be serialized. However, my situation is not this kind of relation and I haven't found how to achieve what I need.

I have a situation where one User have a list of many other Users (their friends):

```
public class User {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public List<User> friends;
}
```

Now, let's suppose that `user1` is friend with `user2` so they are both added in each others friend list :

```
user1.friends.add(user2);
user2.friends.add(user1);
```

This causes a circular reference when serializing (and eventually a StackOverflowException). Indeed, user1's friends contain user2, and user2 friends contains user1, who contains user2.... and so on !

However I cannot just make `transient` the friends property of the `User` class, because I need those friends names and ids. I would rather like the friend property to be excluded at the second level of serialization (by serializing the name and id of each friends, but not the friends' friends).

Here's an exemple of a serialized JSON I would need :

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"user1"
    "friends": [
      { 
        "id":2,
        "name": "user2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"user2"
    "friends": [
      { 
        "id":1,
        "name": "user1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks a lot in advance !